# how can i setup wildcards subdomains in apache linux?

Tags: linux, apache

Currently i am using

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias *.localhost
UseCanonicalName Off
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

I have the above code in the httpd-vhosts.conf but no result.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Enable httpd-vhosts.conf in your httpd.conf.